# Handle Function inside Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My hook function

```
 function useFormInput(initialValue){
   const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
   function handleChange(e){
   setValue(e.target.value);
                           }
    return {
          value,
          onChange: handleChange
         };
    }
```

The way I called them independently inside a main function.

```
    const name = useFormInput('Aziyat');
    const rating = useFormInput('10');
```

As far as I understood, it automatically setValue when I declare them as name and rating(above code).

If I want to change the state of name and rating how do I do?
Also, how can I use handleChange outside of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From useFormInput() hook, you're returning an object `{value,onChange}` properties. You can simply destructure them like so

```
 const {value,onChange }= useFormInput('Aziyat');

// if useFormInput has to be used multiple times in same scope, you can do this way
// Now, to access rating, you will use rating const and to change rating you can use onChangeRating function

 const {value:rating,onChange:onChangeRating} = useFormInput('10');
```

Comment: hey, thank you for your reply.
Let's say I want to setValue of the name, and rating to ("") empty string after rendering them , how do I do that?

Comment: you can do that using useEffect. First, I want to know are you going to use state changer functions on an input or you're going to use them anywhere else too? I'll add the solution according to that @MarkEzberg

Comment: I will use in input form. Would be great!

Comment: @MarkEzberg Check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cookies-0cphll?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Are you always going to use this hook on inputs? @MarkEzberg

Comment: Basically, I was displaying the input and rating on the screen each time user inputs them. And set the value of name and rating to empty string so we can do so again.

Comment: oh ok. If you're calling onChange() function anywhere else, then I'd have done it another way. But for your use case this is best approach, @MarkEzberg